# How to expose services running in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, istio, metallb, charmed-kubernetes

I have installed `Charmed-Kubernetes` on [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/install-local). and then [istio](https://istio.io/) and its [bookinfo](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/) application.

`kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -l app=ratings -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -c ratings -- curl productpage:9080/productpage | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"`

This returns, **Simple Bookstore App**

`kubectl get gateway -> bookinfo-gateway   32s`

`kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system`

Shows external IP address, but when I try to access with `curl` it gives me nothing.

I also tried to access to `kubernetes-dashboard` as described [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-access-kubernetes-dashboard-externally/), it also failed.

Basically, how can I access to these UI s from another PC? I have installed [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/), but still no luck.

Refered :
[No endpoint with dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566764/no-endpoints-available-for-service-for-kubernetes-dashboard)

[Kube-dashboard serviceunavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411598/kubernetes-dashboard-serviceunavailable-503-error)

[Cant access K8 Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275315/how-do-i-expose-kubernetes-service-to-the-internet)

Traffic goes through a network proxy, could it be a problem?

I am newby for Kubernetes.

Comment: Have you configured metallb configmap like mentioned [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/)? Have you tried to get into dashboard with kubectl proxy like mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started)?

Comment: @jt97 yes, metallb `Layer 2 configuration` was used and `kubectl proxy` was running when try to `curl`.I have updated the question, traffic goes through a firewall. Will that be a problem?

Comment: What is your instastructure? It's some vm with ubuntu?If metalLB configuration is correct then I think that firewall/proxy might be the problem here. Additionaly about dashboard check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333637/other-pc-cant-visit-k8s-dashboard).

Comment: @jt97 Ubuntu running on VM.

Comment: @RahulWagh Thanks for the guide. This is not an issue with installation, all things are up and running. Problem with network expose to the network. CNI is working.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with Charmed-Kubernetes. We need to install all services as `juju` and then deploy also with `juju`.

Here `nginx` sample is really running in the system, but MetalLB can not access to it as `juju` configuration hides it.